# Why is the verb "was" skipped sometimes in the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, ellipsis

> The man **offered** to help the flight attendants.

Why is "was" being skipped here? Isn't it:

> The man **was offered**

?

Comment: 'Offered' is the past tense of the verb 'offer'. Past tense is not passive voice.

Comment: There is no passive voice in your first sentence. The subject does the action of the verb, so this is in the active voice.

Comment: The sentence "The man was offered to help the flight attendants" means, if anything, that he was offered as a human sacrifice presumably to appease the gods who might otherwise have disturbed the flight.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's based on the false assumption that those two sentences are equivalent. They're not

Answer (score 1):

For many verbs, the past tense and the past participle happen to have the same form.

So *offered*, for example, can be either past tense:

> He offered her a cake.

or past participle, which is used in several constructions, including perfect:

> I've offered him an apology

and passive

> She was offered an umbrella.